# How to tell if a functional dependency holds in a projected relation?

Tags: functional-dependencies, database-theory

If I start with a relation R with a set of functional dependencies, and I project these FD's onto a relation S, how can I tell determine if certain FD's then hold in the projected relation?

Comment: You could start with the definition of a FD holding. Also "project FDs onto a relation" does not make sense so you could take the time to express what you mean in your question.

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. #YourNotVeryKnowledable #YouShouldTakeTimeBeforeYouMakeIllInformedComments

Comment: What you are apparently trying to say is that if you start with a relation R in which certain functional dependencies hold, and you take a projection S of R, how can you determine whether given FDs hold in S.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we start with a relation R and a set of functional dependencies that hold in R, and we take a projection S of R. (Taking a FD to be a pair of source and target sets of attributes/columns.) Then the FDs that hold in S are:

1. The FDs where

   - the source attributes/columns are in S, and
   - the source set is the source set of one of the FDs originally holding in R, and
   - the target set is the corresponding target set minus the attributes/columns not in S, and
2. All the other FDs in the transitive closure of the set of FDs in 1.

So for given FDs, each holds in S if it is in the transitive closure of the set of FDs in 1.

Note that if one of the original FDs holding in R isn't in 1 then it isn't in 2 either.

Note that a FD among the original ones holding in R is in S iff its target and source attributes/columns are in S.

(Of course, there are other ways of describing the transitive closure of FDs that hold in S. Also there are different choices for 1. I chose FDs for 1 that are in some sense closest to the origial ones holding in R.)